# All possible combinations that differ by "N" elements in Python

Tags: python, numpy, combinations, combinatorics

I am looking for a simple way to find all possible ways to switch `N`elements between two lists `list1` and `list2`, such that the new lists `list1'` differ from `list1` by `N` elements. The two lists will not have common elements (they contain a set of indices, to be more exact). It is the set of all possible `list1'` I need.

Now, I want a function that takes `list1`, `list2` and `N` as parameters, and returns all possible lists where `N` elements have been replaced. The order of elements in each list is not important.

For example, using `N=1`, `list1=[0,1]`,`list2=[2,3]`, I would want to get:
`[([0,2],[1,3]),([0,3],[2,1]),([2,1],[0,3]),([3,1],[2,0])]`, and using `N=2`, I woul want to get `[([2,3],[0,1])]`.

My initial idea was to use `itertools.combinations(list1+list2,len(list1))` and then discard all those elements that differ by more than `N` elements. This works in principle, but the problem is that `list1` and `list2` are rather long, hence creating all combinations is excessive and time-demanding, while `N` will be some value between 1 and 4.

I would not mind a scipy/numpy-solution, using arrays instead of lists.

PS: In case someone wonders, this is for quantum chemistry - I want to find all possible excited slater determinants, replacing `N` occupied MOs with virtual MOs. So if someone knows of a solution in for example `pyscf`, that would be great, too!

Comment: and the referecne list?

Comment: the sizes of the lists should be the same or may be variable?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I clarified what I meant in the first paragraph. list1 and list2 may have different lengths, but the resulting list1' should be as long as list1.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the case for `N=1` at the moment. I don't think you need `combinations` but `product` to generalize for any `N`.

```
def paring(l1, l2):
    partitions = []
    for i1, v1 in enumerate(l1):
        for i2, v2 in enumerate(l2):
            partitions += [(l1[:i1] + [v2] + l1[i1+1:], l2[i2+1:] + [v1] + l2[:i2])]
    return partitions


def list2string(mylist):
    print('\n'.join([''.join(p[0]) + ' ' + ''.join(p[1])  for p in mylist]))


list2string(paring(['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']))
```

Output

```
b1a2 b2b3a1
b2a2 b3a1b1
b3a2 a1b1b2
a1b1 b2b3a2
a1b2 b3a2b1
a1b3 a2b1b2
```

Comment: @Simon Schrader does make sense that `N` is bounded by the minimum length of the two lists?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than generate all possible combinations and filter after, you can track what swaps have already been made so that duplicate recursive calls are eliminated:

```
import copy
def swaps(d, s_w):
   if not s_w:
      yield tuple([tuple([k[1] if isinstance(k, tuple) else k for k in b]) for b in d])
   else:
      for i, a in enumerate(d):
        for j, k in enumerate(a):
           if not isinstance(k, tuple):
              for x, y in ((x, y) for x, m in enumerate(d) for y, t in enumerate(m) if not isinstance(t, tuple) and x != i):
                  _d = copy.deepcopy(d)
                  _d[i][j] = (True, _d[x][y])
                  _d[x][y] = (True, k)
                  yield from swaps(_d, s_w - 1)

n, n2, list1, list2 = 1, 2, [0,1], [2,3]
r = [*set(swaps([list1, list2], n))]
r1 = [*set(swaps([list1, list2], n2))]
```

Output:

```
[((3, 1), (2, 0)), ((0, 2), (1, 3)), ((2, 1), (0, 3)), ((0, 3), (2, 1))]
[((2, 3), (0, 1)), ((3, 2), (1, 0))]
```

Comment: nice! but sometimes it includes the original reference and sometimes not. In your 1st output there isn't and in your second yes

Comment: @cards This generates all possible swaps. `((2, 3), (0, 1))` is the OP's desired output for the second, and `((3, 2), (1, 0))` is another swap possibility.

Comment: got it! I got confused sorry, it makes perfect sense. Thanks! [it was not listed also in the question]

Comment: @cards No problem, you have a nice solution as well.